# Sort list of arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r, sorting

I have list of arrays and I want to pick up the best array (best means that one, which has smallest sum of all values inside the array).

```
v1 = c(5,5,5,5)
v2 = c(6,6,6,6)
v3 = c(7,7,7,7)
v4 = c(8,8,8,8)
v5 = c(1,1,1,1)
v6 = c(2,2,2,2)
v7 = c(3,3,3,3)
v8 = c(4,4,4,4)
arr1 = array(c(v1,v2,v3,v4), dim = c(4,4))
arr2 = array(c(v5,v6,v7,v8), dim = c(4,4))
myList = list(arr1,arr2)
```

Is there any function that can do it? 
I need to do it in such a loop:

```
solve <- function() {
  A <- myList
  while(length(A) != 0) {
    X <- pickBestFrom(A)
    if(isSolution(X)){
      return(X)
      break
    }
    Y <- neighbors(X)
    A <- append(A,Y)
    A <- unique(A)
  }
}
```

Do you think it is better to find each time "best" value from my list, or to order the list first and then pick the first element?

Comment: So, if I understand the problem correctly, you need a `pickBestFrom` function?

Answer (score 1):

If my comment above is right, i.e., *you need a `pickBestFrom` function* then here are two alternatives, with code to time them.

The first sorts the sums and then chooses the smallest list member.
The second chooses the smaller sum using `which.min` and is faster.

```
pickBestFrom1 <- function(X){
    X[[ order(sapply(X, sum))[1] ]]
}

pickBestFrom2 <- function(X){
    X[[which.min(sapply(X, sum))]]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    order = pickBestFrom1(myList),
    which.m = pickBestFrom2(myList),
    times = 1e3
)
```

Second test, with a larger list. `which.min` is still the fastest.

```
list2 <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) array(rnorm(16), dim = c(4, 4)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    order = pickBestFrom1(list2),
    which.m = pickBestFrom2(list2),
    times = 1e3
)
```